# Is a some nonasociative finite dimensional algebra a division algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a nonasociative finite dimensional algebra with a unit such that for every $a,b \in A$, $a\neq 0$, each of the equations $ax=b$, $xa=b$ has a unique solution.

Is it then true the following: for every $a\in A$, $a\neq 0$ there exists a $b\in A$ such that $ab=ba=1$?

Thanks

Comment: I believe there is at least one such algebra, namely the octinions over $\mathbb{Z}/2$.